# Laravel 5.3 Array on routes

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm new to Laravel and still trying to get myself familiar with it's syntax since I originally programmed in Java.

I came across this syntax in one of the tutorials I'm watching.

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses'=>'ProductController@getIndex',
    'as' => 'product.index'
]);
```

I understand that the `ProductController` is the controller class, `@getIndex` is the method (if you will) residing in the `ProductController` class.

**What are `uses`, `as` and `product.index`?** I see that they are pairs of keys and values.

**Can I modify the `uses` and `as` to whatever name I want?**

I don't see `product.index` anywhere in the folder. At first I thought it was a view.

These are the files.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses'=>'ProductController@getIndex',
    'as' => 'product.index'
]);
```

**ProductController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(){

        return view('shop.index');
    }
}
```

**Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['imagePath','title','description','price'];
}
```

Please explain.

I'd appreciate any useful explanation to this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've said is correct. The route is using the ProductController and asking for the getIndex() method. Yup you're free to name the routes how you'd like to, and your methods also.

As the the alias, 'as' is the route name see [here (Named Routes)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes).

```
'product.index'
```

is the route name.

So you could do...

```
Route::get('/', 'ProductController@getIndex')->name('product.index');
```

This would then allow you to use this route for say a redirection.

```
return redirect()->route('product.index');
```

It's totally optional to name a route.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess Route::get('/', 'ProductController@getIndex')->name('product.index'); is much simpler compared to what I have. Is it a good practice to name a route and use global route() method incase necessary?

Comment: Yup, much simpler - the other way had been in the documentation previously, chaining the route name was introduced in Laravel 5. I would say it's good practice, if you need to redirect - it's more accurate to select your route to redirect to.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful, I read the details on the link you provided. I appreciate it.